# Screen record Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

When executing:

```
adb -s localhost:4444 shell screenrecord /sdcard/dcim/rec.mp4
```

I get:

```
ERROR: unable to create video/avc codec instance
WARNING: failed at 280x280, retrying at 1280x720
ERROR: unable to create video/avc codec instance
```

Is it possible to record the screen on Android Wear?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On the LG G Watch, here are some commands you can use to capture a video of the display on a watch with 280x280 display and MPlayer:

```
adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 30 --o raw-frames --verbose /sdcard/test.raw
adb pull /sdcard/test.raw myfile.raw
mplayer -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=280:h=280:format=rgb24 myfile.raw
```

For a 320x320 watch with FFMPEG you can use this:

```
adb shell screenrecord --size 320x320 --o raw-frames /sdcard/test.raw
adb pull /sdcard/test.raw
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 320x320 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 60 -i test.raw  -an -c:v libx264 -filter:v -vf "format=fps=60,yuv420p" test.mp4
```

(Edited July 2015)
This command should work on all Android Wear devices now http://www.tinmith.net/wayne/blog/2014/08/android-wear-screenrecord.htm

Comment: I found vooya to play the LG Wear video on Mac http://www.offminor.de/ Are there better options?

Comment: Using the latest ffmpeg I couldn't get `-vf "format=fps=60,yuv420p"` to work, so used this instead `ffmpeg.exe -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 320x320 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -i test.raw  -an -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p  test.mp4` Note too that I used `-r 10` to get a slower, and more reasonable, video speed

Comment: You can also record from the Emualtor with the same procedure, you just need to set the "Use host GPU" option in the AVD settings.

Comment: I tried doing this from the emulator and for some reason all the videos come out with really weird frame rates no matter what -r value I use? Is this just a typical issues of recording raw video from the emulator or just doing it in general?

Comment: `adb shell screenrecord` and `adb pull` works fine, but what about `mplayer` & `ffmpeg` commands? do I need to install anything else? Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

On **LG G Watch 5.0.1** I use for record:

```
adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 30 --o raw-frames --verbose /sdcard/test.raw
```

For pull the video recorded:

```
adb pull /sdcard/test.raw
```

And finally convert to mp4 video with ffmpeg 2.5.3:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s:v 280x280 -r 25 -i test.raw -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

set r=9 is better

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s:v 280x280 -r 9 -i test.raw -c:v libx264 output.mp4 -y
```