# Is it possible to record the Moto 360 wear screen

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, motorola

I want to know whether is it possible to record the screen of Moto 360 wear using android studio or adb. Screen capture is working fine with Android phone/tab but it is not recording with android wear(Moto 360).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
% adb -s <phone id> forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
% adb -s <phone id> connect localhost:4444
% adb -s localhost:4444 shell screencap -p /sdcard/capture.png
% adb -s localhost:4444 pull /sdcard/capture.png
```

Comment: Not capturing screen(photo) but recording screen(video)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491528/screen-record-android-wear).

Comment: You could do a script that repeat these commands then build a video from screenshot?