# Streaming Wearable to Screen

Tags: wear-os, chromecast

I am working on an Android App for a SmartWatch (ZenWatch 1).

I googled a lot and did not find any solution on how to do this.

**Is there any possibility e.g. ChromeCast, MirrorCast, etc... to get the Screen of the ZenWatch onto a computer/TV?**

Comment: I found a first thing via adb debugging https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTPR_wOXNcA But it is pretty slow. I would not mind if someone finds a faster solution.

Comment: Xlaech shared YouTube link is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of two ways.

1st way (Read the two links, they provide adequate information):

[Screen record Android Wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491528/screen-record-android-wear)

http://www.tinmith.net/wayne/blog/2014/08/android-wear-screenrecord.htm

2nd way:

Run your android wear app on the android wear simulator on your laptop and record your laptop screen.

Comment: 2nd Way: That might be a backup 1st way: i found this allready, but i need to get a live view on the watch. So this would just help, if i could save the video on the pc and stream it with vlc

Comment: Can this work?       http://rominirani.com/2014/07/12/tutorial-cast-your-android-wear-screen-to-all/

Comment: Yeah that will probably work. I posted a simialar solution above. The Problem with my tool was the lag. I will try them out later -baybe some of them are faster ;) Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think there are any other ways to do this. If this answer helped you remember to press the green tick.

Comment: Of course. You can have the bounty as well if no one replies with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to show your Android wearable device's screen on your laptop for development purposes:

**Using Android Studio:**

1. Open Android Studio and launch the app you want to test on your wearable.
2. In Android Studio, from the menu bar, navigate to View > Tool Windows > Device Manager.
3. Your wearable device should be listed under connected devices. Click the dropdown menu next to the device and select "Show screen capture".

This will display the screen of your wearable device within the Android Studio interface.

**Using Scrcpy:**

1. Download and install Scrcpy on your laptop https://scrcpy.org/.
   Scrcpy is a free, open-source tool that allows you to mirror and control Android devices from your computer.
2. Enable Developer Options and USB debugging on your wearable
3. Connect your wearable to your laptop using a USB cable.
4. Open a command prompt or terminal window on your laptop.
   Navigate to the directory where you installed Scrcpy.
5. Type the following command and press enter: scrcpy

This will initiate a connection and display your wearable's screen on your laptop window. You can also use additional Scrcpy commands for functions like screen recording.

Both methods offer effective ways to view your wearable's screen during development. Choose the option that best suits your workflow and preferences.